# Azure Log Analytics Query with WHERE clause produces no results

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I'm querying log entries in Azure Application Insights originating from AppCenter Diagnostics using Azure Log Analytics.
In some log entries i use custom propertys.
Now i'm trying to write a query to show values only with certain properties having a given value.

My original query looks like this and produces the expected result:

```
customEvents
| where (timestamp >= datetime(2019-02-20T09:04:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2019-02-21T09:04:00.000Z)) 
| top 101 by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, name, customDimensions.Properties
| where name == "Navigated to details view"
```

[image: Query result]

Hovering over the "productId" property shows a plus-sign which allows to add a filter criteria:

[image: Filter for property]

Choosing this options extends my query:

```
customEvents
| where (timestamp >= datetime(2019-02-20T09:04:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2019-02-21T09:04:00.000Z)) 
| top 101 by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, name, customDimensions.Properties
| where name == "Navigated to details view"
| where customDimensions_Properties.productId == 4711
```

So far, so good. If i now try to run this query i get the message "NO RESULTS FOUND":

[image: No results found]

Edit:
I also tried adding the where clause on the bottom to the first where clause

```
customEvents
| where (timestamp >= datetime(2019-02-20T09:04:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2019-02-21T09:04:00.000Z)) 
and name == "Navigated to details view" 
and customDimensions.Properties.productId == 4711
| top 101 by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, name, customDimensions
```

Unfortunately no result either.

Edit 2:
I also tried this query to see if i can project the productId property in my query without including it in the where clause:

```
customEvents
| where (timestamp >= datetime(2019-02-20T09:04:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2019-02-21T09:04:00.000Z)) 
and name == "Navigated to details view" 
| top 101 by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, name, customDimensions, customDimensions.Properties.productId
```

But this column is empty:
[image: Project productId]

Is there anything i am missing? Is the tooling a problem and producing a wrong query?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I tried this query but no results as well: 

customEvents
| where (timestamp >= datetime(2019-02-20T09:04:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2019-02-21T09:04:00.000Z)) 
and name == "Navigated to details view" 
and customDimensions.Properties.productId == 4711
| top 101 by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, name, customDimensions

Comment: Remove the last sentence "project timestamp, name, customDimensions", to see if any results output. if it has results, then please add "project timestamp, name, customDimensions.Properties" to the end

Comment: @IvanYang thank you. already tried that but no results either. I also tried projecting customDimensions.Properties.productId but this is empty on every row. will update the question with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use various operators like mvexpand and extend to accomplish your requirement. Please find below sample query. Note that the below one is just a sample query which you may have to tweak a bit to make it work as expected and get the expected output (say if you are expecting output with all the columns of the customEvent at a particular timestamp which has particular productId, etc.)

```
customEvents
| where (timestamp >= datetime(2019-02-20T09:04:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2019-02-21T09:04:00.000Z)) 
| top 101 by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, name, customDimensions_Properties
| where name == "Navigated to details view"
| extend CDP_toString=parsejson(tostring(customDimensions_Properties))
| mvexpand CDP_toString
| project CDP_toString
| where CDP_toString.['productId'] == "4711";
```

Hope this helps!! Cheers!! :)

Comment: Awesome! Never thought it would be that tricky! My final query looks like this now: customEvents
| where (timestamp >= datetime(2019-02-20T09:04:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2019-02-21T09:04:00.000Z)) 
and name == "Navigated to details view" 
| top 101 by timestamp desc
| extend props=parsejson(tostring(customDimensions.Properties)) 
| mvexpand props
| project timestamp, name, props
| where props.['productId'] == "4711"

Comment: I think you can avoid mvexpand in most cases, parse_json as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) allows JSON object walking: `T
| extend d=parse_json(context_custom_metrics) 
| extend duration_value=d.duration.value, duration_min=d["duration"]["min"]`