# Split dynamic column into multiple rows using using mv-expand

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

While using mv-expand on a dynamic value column I expect to get separate rows for each value in the column. Ultimately I want to count each separate value using summarize

The dynamic value column can contain one or multiple values of any number between 1 and 300
like [], [1,3],[1,2,10,30]

I tried using the mv-expand reference but I couldn't make it work.

Tablename
| mv-expand categories=CustomDimension['category_id']

Instead of giving separate rows for each value in the column it creates a new column that has the same dynamic value as the original column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would have to use 'mvexpand' in the query instead of 'mv-expand'. I know [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) is misleading but if you go to your query page and type 'mv-expand' then it doesn't resolve but it does work if you try 'mvexpand'.

To accomplish your requirement, the answer provided by me in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/821b1bdd-5efd-48fe-aac1-73434d0b84e6/view-big-fields-in-query?forum=opinsights) thread should help you. Also for even more advanced example, you may refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803923/azure-log-analytics-query-with-where-clause-produces-no-results) one as well.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!